# ASP.net MVC3 alternatives to DotNetNuke?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, architecture, content-management-system

I am using legacy DNN (CMS + its  portal capabilities, though CMS capabilities are not that important, its portal capabilities are used extensively) to build web apps. Am looking to move into ASP.net MVC3, but am wondering if there are any frameworks which gives me the same portal capabilities as DNN while using ASP.net MVC3.

At the risk of being ridiculous, a simpler way to frame the above question would "how can we use ASP.net MVC3 to build a portal based application like stackoverflow/stackexchange".

I tried best to find answers to this question in meta.stackoverflow, but could not.

These are the meta questions I went thru, to find answers (mentioning here to say that I did my homework before asking this question)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/does-stackexchange-2-0-share-the-same-codebase-with-so

http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/02/11/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/

I am posting this question in SO and not in  meta.stackexchange, because I am looking for building portal based webapps with MVC3. Stackoverflow/stackexchange happens to be one (well known) implementation, there can be other implementations as well.

Edit: I also saw http://code.google.com/p/stacked/, but it does not directly address my "mvc portal" part of the question

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start might be the Orchard project:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Orchard is definitely a MVC3 CMS, but it is not a CMS which supports multiple portals,or does it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 projects I am aware that are open source SO type projects:
[2 are non asp.net](http://www.dalouche.com/wordpress/2010/09/14/open-source-stackoverflow-alternatives/)
There is [Stacked](http://code.google.com/p/stacked/) while Phil made a [HaackedOverflow](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/07/haackoverflow-vs-stackoverflow.aspx) project though I have never seen source code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco V5.O is based on MVC - not sure, unfortunately, what that means exactly in terms of how it affects how you develop.

Also, as of this answer, its just heading into [beta](http://umbraco.com/umbraco-5-status.aspx)